# Why downloading a file with AJAX freezes the whole PHP Web server?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, curl

My situation is :

On a `Debian Linux`, I want to "bind" two reporting technologies, `PHP-Reports` with `JSReport`.

`PHP-Reports` permits me to get data and associated sub-totals with only `SQL` and `JSReport` permits me to precisely format the report with `HTML` and exporting in multiple filetypes once it is done.

The problem is : I want to be able to automate the saving of the report data file in order to get it on `JSReport`.

In order to do that, I have modified a bit the `PHP-Reports` source :

I used `jQuery` to bind on a click on each of the link an `Ajax` script that downloads at the URL on the href of  tag.

Here is the JS part:

```
$(".report_link").each(function() {
   $( this ).bind('click', function() {
      $.ajax({
         url: "/user/ajax/save_a_file.php",
         type: 'GET',
         data: "url=" + $( this ).attr("href"),
         // Ajax needs synchronous execution in this case
         async:false,

         success: function(result) {
            alert("Resultat requête AJAX:" + result);
         },

         error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            console.log("AJAX -> Erreur " + xhr.status + ": " + thrownError);
            console.log("WBREPORT -> Error : can not save file");
         }
      });
   });
});
```

Now my Ajax file :

```
 $complete_url = "";
 $starting_date = "";
 $ending_date = "";

 $url = "";

 if(null !== $_GET['url'])// && null !== $_GET['macros'])
 {
    $url = $_GET['url'];
    if (null !== $_GET['macros'])
    {
       $macros = $_GET['macros'];

       if (null !== $macros['date']['start'])
          $url .= '&macros[date][start]=' . urlencode($macros['date']['start']);

       if (null !== $macros['date']['end'])
          $url .= '&macros[date][end]=' . urlencode($macros['date']['end']);
    }

 }

 $filedir = "/var/www/wbreport/user/data/residents/";
 $report_name = "test.json";
 $report_filepath = $filedir . $report_name;

 $ch = curl_init();

 curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

 $data = curl_exec ($ch);
 $error = curl_error ($ch);
 curl_close ($ch);
```

I tried a lot of ways to make it happen in AJAX file :

- Command line with wget
- Command line with cURL
- And cURL with no use of shell_exec()

It works **outside** of the `PHP Server`, but *freezes* when I click the button. It also freezes when I try to download while there is another same *freezed* download on `PHP Server`, even if `PHP Server` is outside of the shell that executes it.

This isn't the technology I am using to download, it is a much deeper problem. I suggest that `PHP Server` with/and/or `PHP-Reports` has a behavior that freezes the download. But I don't have any idea of what it can be.

Any hints or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: does `PHP-Server` even support multiple concurrent requests?

Comment: The PHP server is single threaded and if you're performing long-running operations, this is entirely expected. In addition, the PHP development web server is meant for use only during testing and not in production.

Comment: `async:false` will lock up your *browser*, too. That's the entire point of it.

Comment: Without `async:false` the AJAX script was not properly executed on PHP-Server. I have know switched it to `true` on Apache and it seem to work well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was simple :

I moved the `PHP-Reports` application from `PHP-Server` to `Apache` and download has been performed correctly.